# lxml finding last optional XML Element

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I am using LXML to process a existing block of XML, where I am wanting to either:

1. Change an element value if the tag is present
2. If not present, create the Element

The problem with (2) is: inserting the Element at the correct place within the block, where the majority of Elements are optional. Note: There is a XSD that defines the structure.

As an example, I am wanting to insert `<d>` which will come after `<c>`if present, otherwise after `<b>` if present, otherwise after `<a>` if present

```
<OuterElement>
    <a>value of a</a> --- Optional
    <b>value of b</b> --- Optional
    <c>value of c</c> --- Optional
    <d>value of d</d>
    <e>value of e</e> --- Optional
</OuterElement>
```

What is the neatest / easiest way of achieving this ? Currently I am looping around the elements with an XPath expression - this feels rather hacky.

Comment: So how does the schema look exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot put the exact schema here, but each Element in the OuterElement example above has minOccurs=0, therefore making it optional. I'm not sure how I can easily work out which is the last present optional element, in order to place `<d>` in the correct position

Comment: Are the child elements of `OuterElement` defined as a sequence or as a choice?

Comment: They are defined as a Sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set up a dummy element template in XSLT with the full sequence and then, while processing the input, push the dummy through a template that checks whether the input has an element of the same name and if so copies that one, otherwise copies the element from the dummy template element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="template">
    <OuterElement>
        <a></a>
        <b></b>
        <c></c>
        <d></d>
        <e></e>
    </OuterElement>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:variable name="template-elements" select="exsl:node-set($template)/OuterElement/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="OuterElement">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$template-elements">
              <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="OuterElement/*">
      <xsl:param name="input"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$input/*[name() = name(current())]">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$input/*[name() = name(current())]"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, for XSLT 1, we need to use the `exsl:node-set` function to convert the parameter result tree fragment to a node-set.